# Is it possible to inherit a final class modifying bytecode somehow?

Tags: java, bytecode, java-bytecode-asm

Is it possible to inherit a final class using bytecode manipulations?

Comment: Wouldn't "composition instead of inheritance" solve your issue? Could you use a wrapper class for what you're trying to do? Please post some details, it is very difficult to advise something if so small amount of information is available... (and vikingsteve is right!)

Comment: `final` is usually there for a reason...

Comment: Which class are you trying to inherit from? One of the standard library ones?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes and no.

You can use bytecode manipulation to change a `final` class to non-`final` on the fly.  This doesn't even break binary compatibility, so there is no risk of class loader / verifier errors.

However, you have to apply the bytecode modifications to the `final` class itself.  You can't do bytecode manipulation on a child class to make it inherit from a `final` parent class.  Or more precisely, if you do that the modified child class will be rejected by the verifier when loaded together with the `final` parent class.

Comment: If you want a specific reference - JVMS section 4.1, page 73 - "Neither the direct superclass nor any of
its superclasses may have the ACC_FINAL flag set in the access_flags item of
its ClassFile structure."

Comment: The JLS also mentions this - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-13.html#jls-13.4.2

Comment: But the question asked about bytecode manipulation, in which case the JLS is irrelevant. The Java language has tons of arbitrary restrictions that aren't present at the bytecode level.

Comment: @Antimony - what the JLS says in this case is relevant: *"If a class that was not declared final is changed to be declared final, then a VerifyError is thrown if a binary of a pre-existing subclass of this class is loaded"*.

Comment: yes it happens to apply in this case, but you can't trust it in general. Some of the errors mentioned in the JLS result from code inserted by the compiler, rather than anything bytecode related. It's best not to worry about the JLS at all when you're not dealing with Java.

Comment: @Antimony - That is your opinion. IMO it is unwise to *completely ignore* non-definitive references when trying to understand something like this. In this case the JLS is relevant, even if not definitive.  And also note that this question is tagged as "java" and "java-bytecode-asm" (... not "jvm" or "some-jvm-language-but-I'm-not-interested-in-java".)  We ARE dealing with Java here ...

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_class_file) describes the class file format. At the offset `10+cpsize` there are 2 bytes defining the access flags of this class. One of these flags is called [ACC_FINAL (0x0010)](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/tutorial-java-class-file-format-revealed/). I suppose you can mask that bit out and make that class non-final.